# Why is this mapping not contractible?

Tags: algebraic-topology

We define the relative homotopy for a pair $(X,A)$ to be the homotopy classes of continuous maps

$$(D^n, S^{n-1},s_0) \to (X,A,x_0)$$

This is technically a continuous map from $D^n \to X$ with the specifications that $S^{n-1} \to A$.

Any continuous mapping $D^n \to X$ is contractible so I am not sure why this specification on the subspace $S^{n-1}$ results in such maps not necessarily being contractible.

Why is a continuous map $(D^n, S^{n-1},s_0) \to (X,A,x_0)$ not necessarily contractible?

We are often told when they are contractible, i.e when $S^{n-1} \to A$ extends to a map on $D^n$.  However, I have never really understood why these maps aren't contractible to begin with.

Comment: Just look at the identity map $(D^2,S^1,s_0)\to(D^2,S^1,s_0)$. If there were a relative homotopy to the constant map at $s_0$, then it would restrict to a homotopy between the identity on $S^1$ and a constant map. However, the identity loop in $S^1$ is essential (another word for "not nullhomotopic").

Comment: I think the issue is that the OP did not factor in the "relative" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, a point of terminology: a map is not said to be contractible (this is a property of spaces), it is said to be nullhomotopic.

Now, when looking at relative homotopy groups, two maps $f,g : (D^n, S^{n-1}, s_0) \to (X,A,x_0)$ are identified if they are homotopic **relatively to** $A$ (in short, "rel $A$"). This means that there must exist a homotopy $H : D^n \times I \to X$ such that all the following conditions hold:

- $H(x,0) = f(x)$ and $H(x,1) = g(x)$;
- For all $x \in S^{n-1}$ and for all $t$, $H(x,t) \in A$;
- And for all $t$, $H(s_0, t) = x_0$.

It is true that, since $D^n$ is contractible, there will always exist a map satisfying the first condition. But it may or may not satisfy the other two; if it does, great the two maps are homotopic rel $A$, but otherwise they may not be. In particular, note that this implies that the two restrictions $f_{| S^{n-1}}, g_{| S^{n-1}} : S^{n-1} \to A$ have to be homotopic, which isn't always true.

To give an explicit example, consider the case where $A = \{x_0\}$. Then you're looking at maps $f : D^n \to A$ such that $f(\partial D^n) = \{x_0\}$, and two such maps are identified when there's a homotopy which is constant on $\partial D^n = S^{n-1}$. This is of course exactly the definition of the homotopy group $\pi_n(X,x_0)$, and you know that these aren't always trivial.

Even when $A$ is bigger than a singleton this may not be trivial. Stefan Hamcke gives an example in the comments: consider the identity of $(D^n, S^{n-1}, s_0)$. If the identity were nullhomotopic rel $S^{n-1}$, this would imply that the identity of $S^{n-1}$ would be nullhomotopic, which is not true for degree reasons.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer! Is is then true that  for any two maps on the disk whose restrictions to the boundary are homotopic then these maps are homotopic as well?

Comment: @asdvn You didn't say, but I guess you are asking if the two maps are homotopy rel $S^{n-1}$? Then no, it is not the case. Consider a constant map $D^2 \to S^2$, and a map that collapses $S^1 = \partial D^2$ to a point to get $D^2 \to S^2 = D^2 / \partial D^2$. Then the restriction of both maps on the boundary are homotopic, but the two maps are not homotopic rel $S^1$ (they represent different elements in $\pi_2(S^2) = \mathbb{Z}$).